# how to press buttons in order android studio

Tags: android

****i have 3 buttons and i want to press these button in order 
that user can't press the second or third button before pressing the first 
and can't press the  third button before the second and the first if he pressed button in order he will win otherwise he will lose

and my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_newgame);
    fox = findViewById(R.id.foxbutton);
    rabbit = findViewById(R.id.rabbitbutton);
    carrot = findViewById(R.id.carrotbutton);
    score = findViewById(R.id.score);

    //declare boolean
    fox.setOnClickListener( this);
    rabbit.setOnClickListener( this);
    carrot.setOnClickListener( this);
    //my button click

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (carrot.isPressed()) {
        scorecount++;
        score.setText("socre:" + scorecount);

        if ( rabbit.isPressed()) {
            scorecount++;
            score.setText("socre:" + scorecount);

            if (fox.isPressed()) {
                scorecount++;
                score.setText("socre:" + scorecount);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

}
```

thanks**

Comment: What is your question? Does your code work? If it does not, what does it do and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear what you mean. You can certainly disable buttons, i.e. when pressed nothing happens and doesn't show any pressed animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enable/disable attribute of button setEnabled(boolean); , and keep checking in onClick() that which is enabled/disabled using isEnabled().